# Append new elements to an object containing list elements

Tags: jquery

I have a variable `origOrder = $("#sortable").find('li');`

and a json object from ajax response `response.lists` which contains list items

how can I add these new lists to `origOrder`?

Thanks. I hope you understand my question.

**EDIT**

I am using jquery-ui sortable. I store the original order of lists to `origOrder` so when the user cancels the sorting I can restore the original lists. So I can't use the `find('li')` again because if the user started sorting the list the origOrder would be overwritten.

Comment: Add to the jQuery collection, or append to the DOM - which do you want to do?

Comment: Try `origOrder = origOrder.add(response.lists);` but I'm not sure you can rely on order being preserved. Personally I would maintain an array of independent jQuery collections which can be looped through to restore the order. That would be more guaranteed to achieve your objective.

Comment: i already tried that but the order is not preserved :(

Comment: Then you have to use my array suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can append like this

```
origOrder = $("#sortable").find('li');

origOrder.append(response.lists);
```

**UPDATE**

for preserving the list before sort you can save it in a variable

```
var origOrderBeforesort = $("#sortable").find('li');
```

and if user apply sorting, you can use old variable `origOrderBeforesort`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly ...

Since merging jQuery collections with `.add()` does not reliably preserve order, you will need to keep an array of collections, each of which is independently reliable.

Initially :

```
var $sortable = $("#sortable");
var origOrder = [$sortable.find('li')];
```

Then, whenever a response containing new list items arrives :

```
origOrder.push($(response.lists));
$.each(response.lists, function(i, item) {
    $(item).appendTo($sortable);
});
```

Then, to restore :

```
$.each(origOrder, function(i, $sublist) {
    $sublist.each(function(j, item) {
        $(item).appendTo($sortable);
    });
});
```

At least, that's the principle. The detail may differ.